Использование слова "мажоритарий", его этимология
В интернете не смог найти полное определение данного слова. На вики "мажоритарный" имеет два значения: 1.Относящийся к большинству.
2.Имеющий отношение к мажоритарной системе.
Но слово "мажоритарий" имеет только одно определение- депутат, участвующий в мажоритарной системе.
Кто-нибудь знает правильные/полные значения этих слов, можно ли "мажоритарий" использовать как существительное слова "мажоритарный"?

https://dzen.ru/a/X6z4GvaKajp46HI1     https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=мажоритарный&mode=slovari

majoritarian (adj.)
"governed or ruled by the majority; supporting the majority party," 1917, from majority + political ending -arian. It seems to have been used first in a German context, in reference to the moderate Majority Socialists, and it is perhaps based on Bolshevik. As a noun by 1920. Related: Majoritarianism.
also from 1917

https://www.etymonline.com/word/majoritarian#etymonline_v_43670
